# getting a jQuery json parsing error when submitting a form

Tags: jquery, json

I have a page in a php application in which I am submitting a form via jQuery.ajax().

I am getting a parsing error in this code:

```
 jQuery('.finishButton').click(function() {

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php?module=PSTeams&func=createClass&teacherid=1',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        classname: jQuery('#className').val(),
        teacherid: '1',
        students: jQuery("select[name='students[]']").serialize(),
        teams: jQuery("select[name='teams[]']").serialize(),
        inquirymodule: jQuery("select[name='inquirymodule[]']").serialize(),
        gradesix: jQuery("#gradeSix").jqxCheckBox('checked'),
        gradeseven: jQuery("#gradeSeven").jqxCheckBox('checked'),
        gradeeight: jQuery("#gradeEight").jqxCheckBox('checked'),
        gradenine: jQuery("#gradeNine").jqxCheckBox('checked'),
        gradeten: jQuery("#gradeTen").jqxCheckBox('checked'),
        gradeeleven: jQuery("#gradeEleven").jqxCheckBox('checked'),
        gradetwelve: jQuery("#gradeTwelve").jqxCheckBox('checked'),
        gradethirteen: jQuery("#gradeThirteen").jqxCheckBox('checked'),
        gradefourteen: jQuery("#gradeFourteen").jqxCheckBox('checked'),
        gradefifteen: jQuery("#gradeFifteen").jqxCheckBox('checked'),
        gradesixteen: jQuery("#gradeSixteen").jqxCheckBox('checked'),
        challenged: jQuery("#challenged").jqxCheckBox('checked'),
        advanced: jQuery("#advanced").jqxCheckBox('checked'),
        esl: jQuery("#esl").jqxCheckBox('checked'),
        studentbackground: jQuery('#studentBackground').val(),
        learninggoals: jQuery('#learningGoals').val(),
        accessNotes: jQuery('#accessNotes').val(),
        startdate: jQuery('#startDate').val(),
        enddate: jQuery('#endDate').val(),
        starttime: jQuery('#startTime').val(),
        endtime: jQuery('#endTime').val(),
        startbreak: jQuery("input[name='startbreak[]']").serialize(),
        endbreak: jQuery("input[name='endbreak[]']").serialize()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
});
```

JSlint says it's valid.  What am I missing?

Comment: a lot of quotes to start

Comment: can you show json what it is generating

Comment: POST and sending query parameters in url?